# Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook

I'm starting out with the Facebook C# SDK and trying to run the MVC Sample on my test server and am running into the following error:

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Facebook.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Facebook.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

Source File: /Views/Facebook/LoginButton.ascx    Line: 1

I've set up several MVC 2.0 projects in the past and have followed the instructions on the getting started section on http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ (added and changed setting in web.config, etc.)

What am I missing in order to run the sample project(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very old sample from the SDK. The problem is that the class Facebook.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl does not exist. That was only in a very early alpha build. I would recommend downloading the new sample to get started. You can get that here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/54371#DownloadId=160969

Comment: Nathan,

How do you access the graph information such as location or hometown. I understand how to get name, email, link, id, etc. but not information that is returned in the following format:

"location": {
      "id": "109650795719651",
      "name": "Los Gatos, California"
   }

Comment: How are you making the request? It may be best to make another question and include a code sample.